# Iterate over column and flag if condition is met row by row into a new column

Tags: r, conditional-statements, iteration, logical-operators

I have a data frame that is composed of and ordered by dates, lines, machines, and sample locations. Additional data is paired with these records as well.

I wanted to iterate over a column in the data frame called F2.trigger and evaluate this logic and report True or False to a new column.

Logic would be: In column "F2.trigger" If value "F2" is followed by value "M" then report in new column "True". If value "F2" is followed by value "N" then report in new column "False". If value "F2" is followed by value "F2" then report in new column "False"

Sample date frame is below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2023-04-01", "2023-04-02", "2023-04-03", "2023-04-04", "2023-04-05", "2023-04-06", "2023-04-07", "2023-04-08"),
                  line = c('G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1'),
                  machine = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1"),
                  sample_loc = c("L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1"),
                  F2.trigger = c("N", "F2", "M", "N", "F2", "N", "F2", "F2"))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

I tried using integers and a `cumsum` and reset sum approach but got no where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `lead` and `lag` functions from `dplyr`.
for detail look here [dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html)

```r
library(dplyr)
df1%>%
  mutate(newc=ifelse(F2.trigger== "F2" &  lead(F2.trigger)=="M",TRUE,
              ifelse(F2.trigger== "F2" &  lead(F2.trigger)=="N",FALSE,
              ifelse(F2.trigger== "F2" &  lead(F2.trigger)=="F2",FALSE,NA       
                     ))))
#>         date line machine sample_loc F2.trigger  newc
#> 1 2023-04-01   G1      M1         L1          N    NA
#> 2 2023-04-02   G1      M1         L1         F2  TRUE
#> 3 2023-04-03   G1      M1         L1          M    NA
#> 4 2023-04-04   G1      M1         L1          N    NA
#> 5 2023-04-05   G1      M1         L1         F2 FALSE
#> 6 2023-04-06   G1      M1         L1          N    NA
#> 7 2023-04-07   G1      M1         L1         F2 FALSE
#> 8 2023-04-08   G1      M1         L1         F2    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you this works well, especially adding in group_by with the other values in my dataset.